# Getting ICDF from PDF

Tags: sampling, negative-binomial-distribution

I have the PDF for the Negative Binomial distribution, parameterized by $\mu$ and $\alpha$:

[image]

How can I find the ICDF, so that given $z \in[0,1)$, $\mu$ and $\alpha$, I can sample from this distribution?

Comment: CDF is cumulative distribution function. So what do you mean be ICDF?

Comment: Inverse Cumulative Distribution Function

Comment: All you have to do is invert the regularized incomplete beta function. 

A better approach might be to note that $\frac1\alpha$ should be an integer and you then add together that many geometric random variables